# 10k-tools lists items I've already dealt with

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

My 10K-tools items currently lists:

[image]

What I have a problem with is that I've flagged both these posts as being "not an answer" and also cast the only "delete" vote that is listed with the second post. However, neither post is being removed from my list of items to review:

[image]
[image]

Why is this the case?